# How to play audio by a specific audio device in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I've looked up around for a way to achieve mainly 3 different things with Android:

- How to getting listed all the audio output and input devices?

I've found out that there's a method added since API 23 on AudioManager instances according to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getDevices(int)) which does this, but there's no documentation about a solution for previous versions. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945313/what-is-the-android-api-for-getting-the-list-of-connected-audio-devices) remains unanswered here at StackOverflow and several places online.

- How to pick up a specific audio output device to stream audio?

The purpose I want to acomplish with this is to select one of the available output devices and stream out the audio by it. Is there a way to do so?

- How to record by a specific input device?

The same that before, specific device usage,  but in the other way around, I mean, to select one of the available microphones and use it to record audio.

Please help me with some guidence, source code or idea, all of them will be very welcome.

Comment: Hi @yadir, did you find a solution to play audio on a specific audio output ?